# How to remove the overlay loader from material table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

How can I remove the overlay loader completely from the table?
(Table used: https://github.com/mbrn/material-table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *OverlayLoading* field to remove the overlay loader style of material-table.

```
<MaterialTable
  columns={columns}
  data={...}
  components={{
    OverlayLoading: props => (<div></div>)
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change loadingType to linear in options:

```html
<MaterialTable
  columns={columns}
  data={...}
  options={{
    loadingType: 'linear'
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override Overlay loading component like this,

```
<MaterialTable
  columns={columns}
  data={...}
  components={{
    OverlayLoading: () => <div />
  }}
/>
```